# Como agregar un valor a un input sin sustituir el que ya esta

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer para cuando le de click algún botón me ponga un número detrás de otro y no me sustituya el valor que está.
Es decir si doy dos clicks al 3 me agregue 33 o si doy click en el 1 y después en el 3 me ponga 13

https://jsfiddle.net/yauf8m8s/

```js
function numero1() {
  var number1 = 1;
  document.getElementById("inputext").value = number1;
}

function numero2() {
  var number2 = 2;
  document.getElementById("inputext").value = number2;
}

function numero3() {
  var number3 = 3;
  document.getElementById("inputext").value = number3;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <input type="text" id="inputext" value="0">
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="numero1()">1</button>
<button onclick="numero2()">2</button>
<button onclick="numero3()">3</button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dado que son funciones que hacen prácticamente lo mismo, donde lo único que cambia es el valor a agregar según el botón que sea presionado, podrías simplificar el código considerablemente si organizas mejor cada botón y sus atributos.

Para ello:

- A los **botones**, les asignaremos una misma clase, a la cual he llamado `btnNumber` (de este modo podremos agregar un listener a todos ellos mediante su clase y su tipo). En consecuencia, ya no necesitaremos invocar una función por cada botón pulsado, por lo que quitamos el `onclick` de cada botón.
- También daremos un atributo `value` a cada botón, dicho valor nos será muy útil, como verás más adelante
- Usaremos [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) para seleccionar los botones y asignarles el listener (habría otras formas de hacerlo en caso de problemas de compatibilidad). Esto nos permitirá invocar **una sola función** cada vez que uno de esos botones sea pulsado.
- En la función a la cual he llamado `agregarTexto`, tomamos el `value` del botón que fue pulsado mediante el uso de `this`, y lo agregamos al input concatenando con `+=`.

De este modo el código queda mucho más simplificado.

**NOTA:** Supuse que el valor inicial `0` que tenías no interesaba guardarlo, por eso lo ha cambiado por un `placeholder`, el cual no afecta a los valores del `input`. Si te interesa mantener el `0` a la izquierda, cambias el `placeholder` por `value="0"` como lo tenías originalmente.

Espero te sirva.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button.btnNumber").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', agregarTexto, false);
});

function agregarTexto() {
  var btnValor = this.value;
  var elInput = document.getElementById("inputext");
  elInput.value += btnValor;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <input type="number" id="inputext" placeholder="0">
</div>
<br />
<button class="btnNumber" value="1">1</button>
<button class="btnNumber" value="2">2</button>
<button class="btnNumber" value="3">3</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, exelente lo pondré en práctica

Answer (score 4):

En lugar de simplemente establecer el valor del input `=` concatenalo `+=`:

```
document.getElementById("inputext").value += number1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene al asignar `=` en vez de concatenar `+=`

Pero puedes **optimizar al máximo** tu código utilizando **sólo Javascript** en pocas líneas con un *pequeño cambio*:

### JS

```
function concatenar(value) {
    document.getElementById("inputext").value+=value.innerHTML;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="display">
  <input type="text" id="inputext" placeholder="0">
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="concatenar(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="concatenar(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="concatenar(this)">3</button>
```

Comment: Exelente, muchas gracias