# Cómo saber el id de un botón al dar click en el que su id es generado dinámicamente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Quisiera saber cómo obtener el id de unos botones que genero dinámicamente por medio de una consulta MySQL.

```
<?php
    while($row =mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $id_c_reactivo = $row['id_c_reactivo'];
?>
        <button id="UploadBtnc_<?=$id_c_reactivo?>" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: La pregunta no termina de quedar clara. ¿Qué es lo que quieres saber exactamente? ¿El ID del botón pulsado? ¿Y desde donde lo quieres saber: en el lado del cliente (JavaScript) o en el del servidor (PHP)? Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Quiero saberlo del lado del cliente con javascript para poder lanzar el evento onclick es un poco confusa tendré que poner todo mi codigo

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu objetivo final?

Comment: Tal vez puedas añadir una clase al botón para que diga que se creo dinámicamente `<button id="UploadBtnc_<?=$id_c_reactivo?>" class="UploadBtnc dinamico" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>` un identificador del lado del servidor.

Comment: [Esta respuesta se parece mucho a lo que quieres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140442/29967). Sería cuestión de añadir una clase a los botones y luego usar `querySelectorAll` para agregarle un *listener* a cada uno de ellos **por clase y por tipo de elemento**, siendo así muy específicos y no asignando *listeners* de forma indiscriminada. En la función usarías `this` para acceder a cualquier atributo del botón presionado. En el enlace puedes hacer una prueba del código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hacerlo con **JavaScript** debes capturar los botones por medio de su clase, recorrerlos para asignarle a cada uno un evento `click` el cual va a disparar una función que capturará su atributo `id`

```js
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName('UploadBtnc');

for(var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++){
  botones[i].addEventListener('click', capturar);
}

function capturar(){
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="UploadBtnc_100" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
<button id="UploadBtnc_101" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
<button id="UploadBtnc_102" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
```

O usando la librería jQuery todo es mas simplificado:

```js
$(".UploadBtnc").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="UploadBtnc_100" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
<button id="UploadBtnc_101" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
<button id="UploadBtnc_102" class="UploadBtnc" value="Subir 
Comentarios">Agregar Comentario</button>
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Bender resulto a la perfeccion para poder disparar un evento onclick

Comment: Bender una pregunta si yo quisiera dispara el evento onclik como lo aria :                                                   
$(".UploadBtnc").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});   $( btn ).click(function(){
            //alert('entreee');
            guardar_comentariosXr(index,id_tallerC[index].value);
        });

Comment: @HectordelaRosaM. no entendí lo que dices en el comentario

Comment: Bender una pregunta si yo quisiera dispara el evento onclik como lo aria :                                                   
$(".UploadBtnc").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
  guardar_comentariosXr(id);
});

Comment: @HectordelaRosaM. sigo sin entender a que te refieres, el evento se dispara con el selector $(".UploadBtnc").click....

Comment: Perdon Bender una disculpa todo claro gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te funcione:

```
 <button id="Imprime tu php con el id de la DB" onclick="myID()">Click me</button>
```

JS y JQuery

```
  function myID(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    //puedes almacenarla en una varible y hacer uso de ese valor en diferentes formas 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una selección **más específica** mediante `querySelectorAll`.

En este código seleccionarías **solamente los botones** que están dentro de la clase `btn-class`, asignándoles un listener.

En la función `leerDatos` obtendrás cualquier información que tenga el botón que haya recibido el clic, por ejemplo el  `id`, el `value` u otro.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.btn-class > button").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', leerDatos, false);
  //console.log(elem);
});

function leerDatos() {
  var btnId = this.id;
  var btnValue = this.value;
  console.log("Presionaste el boton: " + btnId + " y su valor es: " + btnValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-class">
  <button id="btn1" value="1">Botón 1</button>
  <button id="btn2" value="2">Botón 2</button>
  <button id="btn3" value="3">Botón 3</button>
  <hr />
  Otros elementos en la misma clase, que no reaccionarán al clic <br />
  porque <b>no son botones</b>.<br /><br />
  <input type="text" size="50" placeholder="Soy un input text... Haz clic y no pasará nada" />
  <br />En el checkbox tampoco pasará nada al hacer clic: <br />
  <input type="checkbox" placeholder="Soy un input text... Haz clic y no pasará nada" />Check here!
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script>


   $(".UploadBtnc")click(function)(){

      var id=this.id//asi consigues el valor del id de el boton
    alert(id)//muestralo con alert para confirmar que funciona

  </script>
```

Comment: Por favor, mira [answer], las respuestas que son solo codigo no estan bien vistas, debes explicar que hace este codigo y como usarlo. Gracias por el aporte!

Comment: pues puedes hacer lo que quieras una vez que tengas el valor del id enviarlo por ajax insertarlo en una tabla etc..